# where is the '^]' character on an azerty keyboard?

Tags: telnet, escaping

I am currently using telnet and i need to do an escape character (SMTP), where is this character on an azerty keyboard? (linux ubuntu).

Comment: In general, a control-letter combo translates into the letter's ASCII value minus the 0x40 bit (ie, the control character in the same row of the ASCII table).  So control-] is the Group Separator control character -- 0x1D.  How you get that on an Azerty keyboard, though, I haven't a clue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally found it, to input the special character `^]`, and I insist on the fact that it is *one* character, on a Linux Ubuntu (may work on other distrib, does not work on windows) you have to press <kbd>AltGR</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

<kbd>]</kbd> is on the key with those 3 characters : <kbd>°)]</kbd>.

It will not work at all time, I know it works in telnet but on the terminal it prints nothing.

Comment: Also works for some QWERTY non-English keyboards.

Answer (score 7):

Two to the left of Backspace by the looks of it:

[image: QWERTY vs. AZERTY]

**Edit**

I've just read elsewhere that it's ctrl+$ on AZERTY, which makes sense as it's the same physical placement. (http://www.madrouter.com/pemu-pix-emulation-and-dynamips/ then ctrl+f "AZERTY")

Backed up again here: http://www.generation-nt.com/reponses/quitter-telnet-entraide-198084.html?page=2

Comment: No, I'm on Azerty myself and have tried numerous combinations. This one does not work :). Mind the `^`. Would love to know though...

Comment: Just ammended my answer above, apparently it's ctrl+$

Answer (score 2):

On AZERTY keyboard type Control+5 :)!

Comment: This also works on a Finnish qwerty keyboard, which doesn't have a separate ] key (it's AltGr-9).

Answer (score 1):

Well I am using an Azerty Keyboard as I type this :

ctrl-$ will not work. simple as that.

See the enter key ? well from the top of the enter key, go two keys to the left. et voila. no CTRL no nothing. just press it and ^

see ? magic.

Comment: they're not actually trying to type the hat (^) character. In this instance, for example, the notation ^c would equal ctrl+c.

Comment: I confirm ^] in telnet is one character, not two.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azerty keyboard, in most cases I use 'Ctrl'+'$' or 'Ctrl'+'c' or 'Ctrl'+'d'. If does not work I google for alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

I am told that, on a french azerty keyboard you need to press the key to the right of the p, but it should not be before a vowel - if it is, press it twice, and it should work

Comment: OP wants to _send_ the signal `^]`; **not** _type_ "^]".